# Drawable draw() call not executing at the same time on various devices

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable

I have a custom drawable for my action bar which extends `GradientDrawable`. I the drawable itself draws exactly what I want, my issue seems to be WHEN it draws. I developed it on Nexus devices and it works great, exactly as expected, however, when I run it on non-nexus devices it does not function properly. I traced it back to the `draw(Canvas canvas)` call not being called at the same rate as Nexus devices. I added a line of code which replaces the action bar drawable with the same drawable after adjusting its settings and this made it work on all devices but I don't like constantly resetting the drawable as it happens as the user drags across a screen. Is this simply not a concern? Do the manufacturers really get to modify the drawing system that much? Any ideas? Device results and code are included below.

**The drawable's draw() method**

```
/*
* mUnderlineColor, mUnderlineWidth, mToplineColor and mToplineWidth are all
* parameters which change as the user drags. The methods to set them call
* invalidateSelf() after changing the values in the corresponding paints
*/
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        if (Color.alpha(mUnderlineColor) != 0) {
            canvas.drawLine(0, canvas.getHeight()-mUnderlineWidth+1, canvas.getWidth(), 
                    canvas.getHeight()-mUnderlineWidth+1, mUnderlinePaint);
        }
        canvas.drawLine(0, mToplineWidth-1, canvas.getWidth(), mToplineWidth-1, mToplinePaint);
    }

public void setUnderlineAlpha(float alpha) {
    mUnderlineColor = Color.argb(Math.round(alpha * 255), Color.red(mUnderlineColor),
            Color.green(mUnderlineColor), Color.blue(mUnderlineColor));
    mUnderlinePaint.setColor(mUnderlineColor);
    invalidateSelf();
}
```

**Setting the parameters**

```
public void onPageScroll(int xpos) {
        float alpha = mWidthPercentage - (float)xpos / mScreenWidthPixels;
        mFadingUnderline = alpha / mWidthPercentage;
        int actionBarAlpha = 200 + Math.round((255 - 200) * mFadingUnderline);
        mDrawable.setAlpha(actionBarAlpha);
        mDrawable.setUnderlineAlpha(mFadingUnderline);
        //mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawable);
            //The commented line is unnecessary on Nexus devices, but required on
            //everything else.
}
```

**Devices that do not need me to call `setBackgroundDrawable()`***

- Galaxy Nexus (4.2.1)
- Nexus 10 (4.2.1)
- Nexus 7 (4.2.1)
- Nexus S (4.2)
- Motorola Xoom (4.0.4)

**Devices that do require me to call `setBackgroundDrawable()`***

- Transformer Prime (4.1.1)
- Galaxy Tab 7.0+ (4.0.4)
- Acer A500 (4.0.3)

If there is no overhead of resetting the drawable I don't mind so much, it just seems odd to me that Nexus devices all draw after invalidateSelf() and the manufacturer devices don't. Anyone have some input?

Comment: Refreshingly well-asked, by the way.

Comment: Thanks. Our app is having some drawing speed troubles so I have been digging around in the api's trying to improve it so I had plenty of info to provide. I just wish the manufacturers would stop breaking android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`invalidateSelf()` only performs redrawing if the Drawable's callback is set. I imagine on the devices where it succeeds a `getCallback()` would be non-null and on failures it would be null. Why? You got me.

The reason a new call to `setBackgroundDrawable()` works is that that causes the `ActionBar` to invalidate itself. Instead of refreshing, you could bypass and have the `ActionBar` invalidate manually. Don't think it matters too much.

Comment: Ran some logcat outputs and that is exactly the reason. Should I implement a callback somehow? The callback on the devices that work is the action bar container but since that is part of the android.internal package I don't see me getting access to it at runntime.

Comment: I wouldn't. Either invalidate the `ActionBar` manually or simply reset your background drawable each time. I don't see any particular harm.

Comment: I'll just reset then. At least the GC wont be running since it will just be resetting to the same object. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any example of how to implement the getCallBack() ? I've searched in a lot of places and couldn't find how to do it. Should I just use a handler and do the obvious? for unscheduleDrawable and scheduleDrawable the documentation says what can be done, but I don't understand what should be done with invalidateDrawable .